# Prob choosing 1 out of 2 from 11

Tags: probability

Suppose we have 11 items, 2 of which are "good". Someone wins a prize if in 1 turn they pick either of the 2 good items.

Whats the probability the person wins?

I got 3.6% using combinations but not sure if its correct

I want to be able to extend this out into say, if there was 3 items out of the 11 which were good, and the contestant had two goes to choose an item.

Comment: That is far too low.  If you just choose $1$ the probability that it is good is $\frac 2{11}=18.18\%$.

Comment: Not sure your question is clear.  Do you mean you just choose one object or are you choosing two?

Comment: What if they choose 2 from 3 out of 11 where 3 of them are good. Is it still 2/11?

Comment: Your formulation is rather vague: "has the chance to win a prize if.."?... So picking the right one only gives a chance on winning a price? Secondly, what is a "turn" here?

Comment: Please write more clearly.  What does "choose 2 from 3 out of 11 where 3 are good" mean?

Comment: If you are saying:  there are three good ones and eight bad ones and you choose two, then the probability that both are bad is $\frac 8{11}\times \frac 7{10}=\frac {28}{55}\approx 51\%$.  But is that what you meant?

Comment: @lulu you have 11 items, 3 of these items are "good". Someone plays the game and picks two items from the 11. If both of the selections are "good" then they win the prize else they dont

Comment: Oh, you need both to be good?  Ok, then it is $\frac 3{11}\times \frac 2{10}=\frac 3{55}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have $n$ items out of which $m$ are good. In order to win, a person needs to draw a good item in the first turn, the probability of which is $\frac mn$. In the next turn, the person again needs to draw a good item, which can happen with a probability of $\frac{m-1}{n-1}$ since you have $m-1$ good items and $n-1$ total items left. The probability of winning by picking only good items in $m-1$ turns is thus the product,

$$\displaystyle\frac mn\cdot\frac{m-1}{n-1}\cdot\frac{m-2}{n-2}\ldots\frac2{n-m+2}$$

You could have also found this probability by noting that you can select $m-1$ good items out of $m$ good ones in $\binom m{m-1}=\binom m1=m$ ways, and the total number of ways of drawing $m-1$ items out of $n$ items is $\binom n{m-1}$. The required probability is $\displaystyle\frac m{\binom n{m-1}}$.

Answer (score 0):

If you only get one try, then

$$P(win) = \frac{good}{total} = \frac{2}{11}$$

If you get more than one try, its easier to calculate the compliment of not winning:

$$P(win) = 1-P(loss)=  1-\frac{9\cdot 8 \dots }{11\cdot 10 \dots}$$ where the right summand is the product of always losing for however many pulls you want.